# Add CMS block by name in CMS page

Tags: blocks, cms

when we add a block in a CMS page for our multistore now it can only be done like this (I think)

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="55"}}
```

We would much rather use somethin like *block_name* to add blocks - a little more human readable. Can this be done?

Something like

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_name="my_handle_fot_this_block"}}
```

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="block_identifier_here"}}
```

This should work because the block widgets calls `->load(block id)` and the load method on the block model works with both ids and identifiers.

or

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_identifier here"}}
```

Comment: Thx Marius. Both dont work: both variables also imply a block_id like a number dont they ?

Comment: Would it be hard to write a quick phtml file that can access a new variable block_name, call it and print it {{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="custom/anyblock.phtml" block_name="block_name_here"}}

Comment: Both of them should work with ids and strings. Just make sure the identifiers exist.

Comment: cool thx. Ahum. Had to refresh cache because changing of blocks. My bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have custom logic for widgets and don't have cms/widget_block or cms/block as the parent class of your widget there is a trick on how to make it works.

The idea is:

```
{{widget type="your_module/your_widget_class" template="foo/bar/your_teamplate.phtml" instance_id="XXX"}}
```

then, implement _beforeToHtml() in your_module/block/your_widget_class and add something like:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    parent::_beforeToHtml();

    $instanceId = $this->getDataUsingMethod('instance_id');

    if ($instanceId) {
        $widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($instanceId);

        if ($widget) {
            $this->addData($widget->getData());
            $this->addData($widget->getWidgetParameters());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This trick will load your class and add the ability to render it by playing with instance_id.

Happy coding ;)